# reorganize keys of containers map

Tags: matlab, sorting, containers, key

I create by iteration with a for loop a container map on matlab whose keys are for example :

```
keys(tab) = 1x3 cell array
{'long_Kinn'} {'long_pro'} {'long_tal'}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to bypass the alphanumeric ordering of the keys and reorganize them as : ?

```
keys(tab) = 1x3 cell array
{'long_pro'} {'long_tal'} {'long_Kinn'}
```

*Matlab version 2020a*

Comment: To what end? A map is designed to be quick to index, which is probably helped by the keys being ordered internally, what dictates the order you want to display them in?

Comment: the display in a precise order of these keys in a LaTeX table

Comment: The only way to re-order any cell array, map or not, is to know the order or conditions for that order up front. Can you please add how MATLAB is meant to "know" the order you want?

Comment: I have a list of choice as : list={tal,pro,kin}

Comment: OK, so can you not just use that list directly? Or prepend `'long_'` and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map is, by definition, an unordered container. If the order is important, use an array, not a map.

For example, if you currently map those keys to values A, B and C, create a cell array as follows:

```matlab
tab = {};
tab{:, end + 1} = {'long_pro'; A};
tab{:, end + 1} = {'long_tal'; B};
tab{:, end + 1} = {'long_Kinn'; C};
```

...Which of course you’d do in your loop. Now insertion order is preserved.

Appending to an array is not recommended, but this will be faster than adding to a `containers.Map` anyway. The orientation of the cell array above was chosen to make appending most efficient.

If you need to use your cell array for lookup, you can do:

```matlab
value = tab{2, strcmp(tab(1,:), key)};
```

This is not as pretty as lookup in a map, but it works just as fine as long as you don’t have a humongous amount of keys in your container.

---

Alternatively, consider using a `table` object, since you seem to be working with tabular data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your explanations. I was inspired by your answer to solve the problem. Thanks again !